# Help checking relationships between $h$ and $f$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11754), and hoping for help checking a couple of details.

The paper considers some function $f$, which I guess we can assume has whichever properties are necessary for what we're going to do.

1. At the bottom of p. 27, the authors define $h(x) := f\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)$
2. At the bottom of p. 29, they claim that $h'(0) = -f'(0)$
3. Also at the bottom of p. 29, they claim that $h''(0)/2 = f'(0) + f''(0)/2$

I think that the second and third points above are incorrect. Here is my work.

Regarding the first derivative, we have

\begin{align*}
h(x) &= f\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)\\
\implies h'(x) &= f'\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\right)\\
\implies h'(0) &= -f'(1)
\end{align*}

Regarding the second derivative, we have

\begin{align*}
h'(x) &= f'\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\right)\\
\implies h''(x) &= f''\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\right) + f'\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right) \frac{2(1+x)}{(1+x)^4}\\
\implies h''(0) &= f''(1) +2f'(1)\\
\implies \frac{h''(0)}{2} &= f'(1) + \frac{f''(1)}{2}
\end{align*}

So basically, I think they have some typos where the argument for $f'$ and $f''$ should be $1$ instead of $0$.

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Your working is certainly correct, but it may be that given the particular way $f$ was defined, we have $f^{\prime}(0) = f^{\prime}(1)$ and $f^{\prime\prime}(0) = f^{\prime\prime}(1)$.